# Why does int do not require to be a constant and/or passed-by-reference in functions?

Tags: c++

I am a totally newb and have recently bought a book titled "Profession C++ fourth edition". The only coding experience is briefly making my own addon with Lua in WoW.

The question is why doesn't "int" need to be a constant or passed by reference  while "string" has be to a constant and passed by reference?

```
void setFirstName(const std::string& firstName);
const std::string& getFirstName() const;

void setEmployeeNumber(int employeeNumber);
int getEmployeeNumber() const;
```

I do get the concept of constant as well as the reason for passing by reference, not by value. But why is it not a case for integer values?

Comment: "*[...] while "string" has be to a constant and passed by reference?*" - it does **not** have to. Where did you read that? In that book?

Comment: Are you sure you do get the reason for passing by reference? Because if you do, it should be obvious that it doesn't apply to integers. It may help if you explain why you think `setFirstName` takes its parameter by `const&`. If you have that understanding wrong, that's the issue.

Comment: Because an int is 4 bytes long and a reference is 8 byte long (on 64-bits machines). Therefore, it's less costly to copy the int than to pass it by ref.

Comment: Constant and `const` are two different things.  A *constant expression* is one that can be evaluated at compile time. `const` means read-only.

Answer (score 6):

`string` doesn't *need* to be passed as a constant or by reference. It's just more efficient to do so if the function doesn't need to modify or preserve a copy of the string anyway, because `string`s can be arbitrarily huge, and passing by value would require copying their contents; not fun if it's a `string` made by slurping a 1 GB file, so calling the function involves allocating and populating a solid 1 GB of new memory.

Passing by `const` reference, rather than mutable reference, is to avoid surprises. From the caller's perspective, `const` reference and passing by value give the same guarantees: The caller's `string` won't change. But if the function accepts a mutable reference, the caller's `string` might change as a result of the call, and now they need to back it up if they need to preserve the original value.

None of that means you *can't* pass `string` in other ways. If you need a personal copy of the `string` (to store beyond the length of the call, or to mutate without affecting the caller), [accept it by value instead of `const` reference](https://web.archive.org/web/20140113221447/http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/) (it will be more efficient than receiving `const` reference, then copying, in the case where the caller passes you an r-value). If you need to be able to mutate the caller's value, accept by mutable reference. But if you don't need to do either, the default should be `const` reference; it's fast, and it simplifies the API for the caller, who doesn't need to worry about their arguments getting changed.

This optimization just isn't relevant for `int` though. Where a `string` can be anywhere from a handful of bytes to GB of data, an `int` is a fixed size (implementation dependent, but typically 2-4 bytes), so the cost of copying it in by value is on the same order of magnitude as the cost of passing the reference (likely slightly cheaper than passing a reference actually, since the reference both reduces memory locality and is usually implemented as a pointer, which is often larger than the `int` itself).

Point is, you have all the same options with `int` as with `string`. It's just that you need to be more careful about copies with `string`, because it can bloat your memory usage and slow your code; no matter how you pass `int`, it's not going to make a huge difference.