# Passing const &variable to function instead of variable

Tags: c++

Why many people pass const &variable to function instead of just variable? I think it gives the same result, doesn't it?

```
//For example many people use this:
int add(const int &a, const int &b)
{
    return a+b;
}

//instead of this:
int add(int a, int b)
{
    return a+b;
}
```

Comment: For bigger classes, as `std::string`, `std::vector`, ..., that avoid extra copies.

Comment: For built-in types, as `int`, pass by value is preferred.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54155990/why-does-int-do-not-require-to-be-a-constant-and-or-passed-by-reference-in-funct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because one gives you the argument by a reference, rather than a new object.

Therefore you can store the reference for later use. If the object passed by argument is modified later, the stored reference will give you the modified value. If you had passed by value, then that copy of the original object would be completely disassociated from the original.

---

Also, because, it avoids copying the referred object.

For a small, trivially copyable type like `int`, the indirection is more expensive<sup>†</sup> than a copy, so it makes no sense whatsoever, but for things like dynamic data structures such as maps and strings, this makes a world of difference.

Besides, some class types are non-copyable so you don't have the option of passing them by value.

Then there is the case of implementing the copy constructor. You have to pass by reference, because if you pass by value, the argument must be copied, so the copy constructor must be called, so the argument must be copied, so the copy constructor must be called, so ... ad infinitum.

<sup>†</sup> Algthough it probably makes marginal difference, and if the function is expanded inline - no difference whatsoever.

Comment: Yes, but i thought that (const int &a) and (int a) means exactly the same, because you can't edit a variable within function if you didn't pass it with & symbol, am i wrong?

Comment: I mean, if you pass just a variable (int a) and you edit it within the function the a variable in main didn't change, is that true?

Comment: @Nerfi they don't mean the same. One means that the object is copied, and another means that it is referred to indirectly. In case of passing by value, you *can* modify the value - it's just that the object within the function is separate from the one that you passed in. Regardless of these differences, both alternatives are similar in regard that neither can be used to modify some integer outside the function.

Comment: Okay, now i understand everything, thanks so much :D